# Missing leading zeroes of date in Hive partition using Spark Dataframe

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am adding a partition column to Spark Dataframe. New column(s) contains year month and day.
I have a timestamp column in my dataframe.

```
DataFrame dfPartition = df.withColumn("year", df.col("date").substr(0, 4));
dfPartition = dfPartition.withColumn("month", dfPartition.col("date").substr(6, 2));
dfPartition =  dfPartition.withColumn("day", dfPartition.col("date").substr(9, 2));
```

I can see the correct values of columns when I output the dataframe eg : `2016 01 08`

But When I export this dataframe to hive table like

```
dfPartition.write().partitionBy("year", "month","day").mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("testdb.testtable");
```

I see that directory structure generated misses leading zeroes. 
I tried to cast column to String but did not work.

Is there is a way to capture two digits date/month in hive partition

Thanks

Comment: what kind of type does your column for the dates have? if it is an integral type this probably is the reason why he deletes leading zeroes in the parsing process.

Comment: its String and I also do substring on that column ( which returns String too ) also I can see 0's in the Dataframe output.

Comment: This looks like a bug in spark: you do have the correct datatypes (strings) that should retain the 0's. Feel free to ask on the spark user's list: they may ask you to file a report.

Answer (score 3):

Per [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery), partition-column-type inference is a *feature* enabled by default. OP string values, since they are interpretable as ints, were converted as such. If this is undesirable in the Spark session as a whole, one can disable it by setting the corresponding spark configuration attribute to `false`:

```scala
SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", value = false)
```

or by running the corresponding `SET key=value` command using SQL. Otherwise, one can individually-counteract it at the column level w/ the corresponding Spark-native [format-string function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@format_string(format:String,arguments:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) as J.Doe suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Add leading zeros to Columns in a Spark Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047444/add-leading-zeros-to-columns-in-a-spark-data-frame)

you can see the answer of how to add leading 0's with this answer:

```html
 val df2 = df
        .withColumn("month", format_string("%02d", $"month"))
```

I tried this on my code using the snippet below and it worked!

```
            .withColumn("year", year(col("my_time")))
            .withColumn("month", format_string("%02d",month(col("my_time")))) //pad with leading 0's
            .withColumn("day", format_string("%02d",dayofmonth(col("my_time")))) //pad with leading 0's
            .withColumn("hour", format_string("%02d",hour(col("my_time")))) //pad with leading 0's
            .writeStream
            .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour")
```